# Programs that move around in memory

Tags: code-golf

It's time for some quines! Well, sort of. This challenge is to create the smallest program that could move around in memory, i.e. if a program is resident in 2000:0100, the program should move to say, memory address be7a:3470.

### Rules

1. The memory address to move in should be pseudorandom.
2. It's still valid if it's a moving file around in the hard drive.
3. If it jumps around the RAM it should go to another segment in RAM.

I call these programs transposons, after the genes that move all around the DNA of an organism. Happy golfing! Contest ends May 9, 2014.

Comment: Is main() {fork();} is a valid solution?

Comment: Oops, I haven't thought of that . . . No. It has to go to another location in the hard drive, and it has to move itself.

Comment: By pseudorandom do you mean not fixed in the way of doing it? The elements of my programs are not in contiguous storage locations. Logically one program, physically separate parts when running. My programs move on disk as they are paged in and out of storage. What does 2. mean?

Comment: 2. means it has to move around to other locations in the hard drive. Sometimes I think I'm the only partial mind reader . . . . And also it has to be a language in which your programs are in contiguous locations.

Comment: This question badly needs clarifying. The answers generally don't seem to match what I'd consider the specification to mean, which means that people generally have different interpretations of what the specification means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bash , 12 bytes

Requires root permissions

```
mv /bin/mv ~
```

7 bytes if you already are in /bin

```
mv mv ~
```

Comment: Does not conform to the rules. You have to specify which target location is . . .

Comment: Edited, is it ok now?

Comment: I know this isn't May 9th, but it's close to it. You Win!

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the spec at all. It isn't moving itself on the disk at all. It's moving the operating system's rename-a-file program to a different place on the disk instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 2 bytes

```
$0
```

Moves itself to a new memory address when it is assigned a new process.

To move to a different spot on the harddrive it takes a few more:

```
cat $0>x
```

Answer (score 0):

**COBOL** (Enterprise COBOL) One 72-character line, 11 significant characters

```
   ID DIVISION
```

That's the smallest (source) I can get which can be moved around (unless I need to make it shorter).

To do the moving:

```
   ID DIVISION 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION  
   CALL "GOLF006" 
   CANCEL "GOLF006"
   CALL "GOLF006"
```

GOLF006 is the name of the stored program. This CALLs the program (using DYNAM compiler option to load the program dynamically), which program then returns to the CALLer having done its work. The second program then CANCELs the CALLed program (confusingly, CANCEL just causes the program to be "removed" from memory) and then CALLs the same program again, so a new one will be loaded.

I suspect the question will be updated soon...

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (shamefully large):

```php
<?file_put_contents(dirname($f=__FILE__).'/'.microtime(1).'.php',file_get_contents($f));unlink($f);
```

`file_put_contents($file,$content);`: write a file, create if it doesn't exist

`file_get_contents($file);`: read a file

`dirname($path)`: gives the directory name of a path

`microtime($float)`: returns a timestamp with microseconds (you can use `rand` or `mt_rand` here)

`unlink($file)`: deletes a link to a file, ultimately deleting a file is no other link exists

`__FILE__`: path of the current file being executed.